# Resharper's multiple enumeration warning NOT showing when iterating with LINQ extension method

Tags: c#, linq, resharper, ienumerable, enumeration

I'm trying to figure out why is Resharper not showing me a warning about possible multiple enumeration on first method's `secondCollection` usage, while properly showing it in second method. Can't resharper create some kind of evaluation tree as when iterating with loops? I'm just curious, seems like LINQ is being treaten differently.

```
private bool LinqMethod(IEnumerable<string> firstCollection, IEnumerable<string> secondCollection)
{
    return !firstCollection.Any(e => secondCollection.Any(c => c != e));
}

private bool LoopMethod(IEnumerable<string> firstCollection, IEnumerable<string> secondCollection)
{
    foreach (var elementA in firstCollection)
        foreach (var elementB in secondCollection)
            if (elementA != elementB)
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

### edit

I've updated my R# to version 9.1.3 - same behaviour. Additionally if I'll inline second `Any()` call, I'll get this, still not showing the warning

```
return !firstCollection.Any(e =>
{
    bool any = false;
    foreach (var c in secondCollection)
    {
        if (c != e)
        {
            any = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return any;
});
```

However if I'll unroll first `Any()` call, I'll get the proper warning:

```
bool any = false;
foreach (var e in firstCollection)
{
    if (secondCollection.Any(c => c != e))
    {
        any = true;
        break;
    }
}
return !any;
```

Comment: I checked now, showing on my side, :)

Comment: @X-TECH Is it? What version are you using? I'm not seeing it on VS 2012 + R# 8.1. Maybe it's time for me to update then :)

Comment: Yes, VS 2013, Resharper 9.0

Comment: `private bool LoopMethod(IEnumerable<string> firstCollection, IEnumerable<string> secondCollection)
        {
            var elementBs = secondCollection as string[] ?? secondCollection.ToArray();
            return firstCollection.All(elementA => elementBs.All(elementB => elementA == elementB));
        }`

Comment: Thank you, but I'm aware of how to deal with the warning. What I was trying to find out was why wasn't I warned in first scenario. I've updated the answer - I guess it might somehow related with Visual Studio's version.